# how to know if the Element class is empty or null in Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to gather the images of a list of articles using the Jsoup library from [this](http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/) url.

When an article hasn't an image embedded I use a standard picture. Here is what I do:

```
for(Element img : document.select(".rullo .rullo-item .lazy>a img[src]")) {
    String imageMainUrl = img.attr("src");
    if(img.attr("src") == null || img.attr("src").equals("") || 
           img.attr("src").isEmpty()){
        images.add(bmp);
    } else {
        String newString = imageMainUrl.replace("data:image/gif;base64,", "");
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageMainUrl, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);                  
        images.add(bitmap);
    }                   
}
```

But the problem is that it never enter in the `if` section; how can I know if the element is empty or null? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem!
Here is the code:

```
for(Element picture : document.select(".rullo .rullo-item picture")) {
    Elements imageElement = picture.getElementsByClass("attachment-rullo");
    String imageUrl = imageElement.attr("data-src");
    if(imageUrl == null || imageUrl.equals("")){
        images.add(bmp);
    } else {
        try{
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageUrl).openStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            images.add(bitmap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            images.add(bmp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            images.add(bmp);
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to solve my my problem by selecting the parent of the image: if the parent has no content the article doesn't have an picture embedded otherwise it has a picture embedded.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
for(Element img : doc.select(".rullo .rullo-item .lazy>a img[src]")) {
        String imageMainUrl = img.attr("data-src");
        URL imageurl = null;
        try {
            imageurl = new URL(imageMainUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final long imageSize = imageurl.openConnection().getContentLength();

        if(img.attr("src") == null || img.attr("src").equals("") ||
                img.attr("src").isEmpty() || imageSize > 0){
            images.add(bmp);
        } else {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageMainUrl, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            images.add(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

I noticed that the actual image url is under data-src and not src.

Comment: I've used the data-src attribure as you suggested and now the url I get is correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to print out the `imageMainUrl` using `Log.i("value",imageMainUrl);` you will traverse the problem like that.
and also post `html DOM` of the articles from where you fetch the images.

Comment: the for loop only iterate the elements with image in it, so ´imageMainUrl´ has always content in it